# Strategies for developing 'cross platform' native mobile apps

Tags: mobile, cross-platform

If I want to target only iOS, Android and optionally Blackberry, what options are available in terms of reusing the same code base (write once, put target multiple platforms on compilation)

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices.html)

xamarin.com

phonegap.com

(Full list):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development